# Output truncated ( img.sum(axis=2)

Tags: python

Can you pls explain the axis 2 part. 
img.sum(axis=2)

How does the RGB output got truncated? Thanks

output:
    (480, 480, 3)
    (480, 480)

```
# Load the image into an array: img
img = plt.imread('some_random_image.jpg')

# Print the shape of the image
print(img.shape)

# Compute the sum of the red, green and blue channels: intensity
intensity = img.sum(axis=2) 

# Print the shape of the intensity
print(intensity.shape)

# Display the intensity with a colormap of 'gray'
plt.imshow(intensity,cmap='gray')

# Add a colorbar
plt.colorbar()

# Hide the axes and show the figure
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question but this is what I can tell:

`sum(axis=2)` means you are doing a sum in the direction of the 2nd element of the array `img.shape` (which equals to [480, 480, 3]

So `sum(axis=2)` is going to make the summation of
`img[:, :, 0] + img[:, :, 1] + img[:, :, 2]`

thus you obtain an array of shape (480,480) where each element is equal to:

```
img[i, j] = img[i, j, 0] + img[i, j, 1] + img[i, j, 2]
```

you now have only a 2D array because by default the np.sum function reduces the size of the array

If you want to keep a 3D array, do `img.sum(axis=2, keepdims = True)`